# Spring MVC : Common param in all requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I have many controllers in my Spring MVC web application and there is a param `mandatoryParam` let's say which has to be present in all the requests to the web application.

Now I want to make that param-value available to all the methods in my web-layer and service-layer. How can I handle this scenario effectively?

Currently I am handling it in this way:

... controllerMethod(**@RequestParam String mandatoryParam**, ...)

and, then passing this param to service layer by calling it's method

Answer (score 11):

```
@ControllerAdvice("net.myproject.mypackage")
public class MyControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void myMethod(@RequestParam String mandatoryParam) {

        // Use your mandatoryParam
    }
}
```

`myMethod()` will be called for every request to any controller in the `net.myproject.mypackage` package. (Before Spring 4.0, you could not define a package. `@ControllerAdvice` applied to all controllers).

See the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) for more details on `@ModelAttribute` methods.

Comment: Is possibile to use this method to set content-type, encoding headers and so on of the controller?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Alexey for leading the way.

His solution is:

- Add a @ControllerAdvice triggering for all controllers, or selected ones
- This @ControllerAdvice has a @PathVariable (for a "/path/{variable}" URL) or a @RequestParam (for a "?variable=..." in URL) to get the ID from the request (worth mentioning both annotations to avoid blind-"copy/past bug", true story ;-) )
- This @ControllerAdvice then populates a model attribute with the data fetched from database (for instance)
- The controllers with uses @ModelAttribute as method parameters to retrieve the data from the current request's model

I'd like to add a warning and a more complete example:

Warning: see JavaDoc for ModelAttribute.name() if no name is provided to the @ModelAttribute annotation (better to not clutter the code):

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared
>   attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type),
>   based on the non-qualified class name:
>   e.g. "orderAddress" for class "mypackage.OrderAddress",
>   or "orderAddressList" for "List<mypackage.OrderAddress>".

The complete example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ParentInjector {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void injectParent(@PathVariable long parentId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("parentDTO", new ParentDTO(parentId, "A faked parent"));
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/parents/{parentId:[0-9]+}/childs")
public class ChildResource {

    @GetMapping("/{childId:[0-9]+}")
    public ChildDTO getOne(@ModelAttribute ParentDTO parent, long childId) {
        return new ChildDTO(parent, childId, "A faked child");
    }

}
```

To continue about the warning, requests are declaring the parameter "@ModelAttribute ParentDTO parent": the name of the model attribute is not the variable name ("parent"), nor the original "parentId", but the classname with first letter lowerified: "parentDTO", so we have to be careful to use model.addAttribute("parentDTO"...)

Edit: a simpler, less-error-prone, and more complete example:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RestController
public @interface ProjectDependantRestController {

    /**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     *
     * @return the suggested component name, if any
     */
    String value() default "";

}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = ParentDependantRestController.class)
public class ParentInjector {

    @ModelAttribute
    public ParentDTO injectParent(@PathVariable long parentId) {
        return new ParentDTO(parentId, "A faked parent");
    }

}

@ParentDependantRestController
@RequestMapping("/api/parents/{parentId:[0-9]+}/childs")
public class ChildResource {

    @GetMapping("/{childId:[0-9]+}")
    public ChildDTO getOne(@ModelAttribute ParentDTO parent, long childId) {
        return new ChildDTO(parent, childId, "A faked child");
    }

}
```

Comment: Now comes the trouble of getting this documented by Swagger. Not doable. I created an issue: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2653